# Intermittent frequency drops in realtime Websocket feed using Windows 10 Hotspot

Tags: node.js, windows, websocket, real-time

I'm running a node.js Websocket server under Windows 10 which other devices can connect to via bridged Mobile Hostpot.

The final purpose will be to receive realtime motion/orientation data from connected phones but for now I'm testing by sending random data from the phone to the server every 40ms.

The interval between successive messages is usually in the 30 - 50ms range, as expected. But every 30-40 seconds it will stutter, with up to 500ms between successive messages and then a flurry of the late messages with 0 or just a few ms between them. After 10 seconds or so of this stuttering, it returns to a steady stream for about 30 seconds, before the pattern starts again.

I've tried using the ws package and uWebsockets.js, same results for both. Also tried secure wss:// and insecure ws:// protocols, same results for both. I'm aware of Nagle's algorithm; I've used setNoDelay(true) on the socket underlying the Websocket, and added TcpNoDelay and TcpAckFrequency registry entries.

Same results from Safari on iPhone and desktop Chrome on Macbook Pro as clients. Minimal network traffic (<50kB/s, i.e. just the websocket packets, no background processes hogging the bandwidth) measured on the W10 server machine.

Here is an example of intervals, with the stuttering in bold text:

...
cur: 50
cur: 26
cur: 38
cur: 38
cur: 43
cur: 37
cur: 43
cur: 41
cur: 40
cur: 45
cur: 33
**cur: 173
cur: 1
cur: 1
cur: 0
cur: 147
cur: 0
cur: 3
cur: 0
cur: 32
cur: 50
cur: 153
cur: 1
cur: 1
cur: 1**
cur: 36
...

Any suggestions as to how to stop this clumping from happening, and getting a steady stream, hugely appreciated. Thank you.